# ul bg not showing behind all li

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a vertical menu off of a horizontal menu on a webpage with css. The problem is the bg only shows behind the first item. I can fix this issue by putting a fixed size, but that doesn't look very good.

[image: my problem]

I am using the following html code:

```
<div id="topmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Patches</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Scripts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">RTE Tools</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Textures</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Utilities</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I think the issue is under #topmenu ul ul..

And here is ALL my css for #topmenu:

```
#topmenu
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#topmenu ul
{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#topmenu ul li
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#topmenu ul li a:hover
{
    color: #04acec;
}

#topmenu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#444;
}

#topmenu ul ul
{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
    display: none; /* hide it */
    position: absolute;
    top:2.3em;
    left: 0;
    width:10em;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#topmenu ul ul li
{
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#topmenu ul ul li:first-child a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#topmenu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#topmenu ul li:hover ul,
#topmenu ul li.hover ul 
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I really appreciate help, I've been messing with it all night.

Comment: You want a BG behind Patches, Scripts etc.?

Comment: @hungerstar yes. Patches, scripts, etc. are <li> in a sub <ul>

Comment: Okay.  Are you trying to get that rouded border around all of them also?  Or is that just for the first item?

Comment: @hungerstar I am trying to do this: http://puu.sh/3D85F/754455caa3.png  without setting a fixed height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `height: 36px;` from `#topmenu ul` gets the result you are looking for.  If you meant to set the height of the **first** `ul` you should use the child selector `>` like this `#topmenu > ul`.

Comment: Thank you so much!, I forgot that #topmenu ul applies to ALL sub ul's as well.

Comment: Check your margins and padding for that sub `ul` as it will no longer have `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` applied to it if you use `#topmenu > ul`.